# {listened/have listened} the recordings {several/too many} times

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, quantifiers

If I want to say to anyone that

> I **listened** the recordings **several** times today.
>
> I **have listened** the recordings **too many** times today.

Which form is the correct form of the sentence? If none, how should it be phrased correctly?

Comment: Please check a dictionary for the use of "listen" and in particular, does "listen" have a direct object.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not what you're asking about, but "listen" does not take a direct object - it requires "to". So does "say", for the person you are saying something to.

With that correction, both your sentences "I listened to the recordings several times today" and "I have listened to the recordings too many times today" are perfectly natural and grammatical, but they mean different things.

"Several" means something like "more than two, but probable not more than about five". It doesn't say whether it was too many times. "Too many" means "more than I wanted/needed/was good for me" - it could be just three times (you probably wouldn't say it for twice), though it's likely to be more.

The sentences are also different in using the simple past ("I listened") versus the present perfect ("I have listened"). Both are perfectly good, and have the same objective meaning, but change the way you are choosing to relate to the events. When you use the simple past you are treating the sequence of events of listening as finished. When you use the perfect, you are saying there is some present relevance - probably that you are treating the sequence of events of listening as still continuing.